# Emulating VFACE Semantic in PS_2_0 Shader

Tags: directx, direct3d, hlsl, shader

I am doing a bit of work on some of our HLSL shaders, trying to get them to work in SM2.0. I've nearly succeeded but one of our shaders accepts a parameter:

```
float alignment : VFACE
```

My understanding from MSDN is this is an automatic var calculated in case I need it, but it's not supported under SM2.0... so, how might I reproduce this? I'm not a shader programmer so any (pseudo) code would be really helpful. I understand what VFACE *does*, but not how I might calculate it myself in a pixel shader, or in a VS and pass it into the PS. Calculating it per-pixel sounds expensive so maybe someone can show a skeleton to calculate it in a VS and use it in a PS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Because `VFACE` means orientation of the triangle (back or front) and the VS or PS stages have not access to the whole primitive (like in SM4/5 GS stage).

The only way is to render your geometry in two passes (one with back face culling, the other with front face culling) and pass a constant value to the shader matching `VFACE` meaning.

Comment: Doesn't VS get given the face-normal of the triangle, and have access to the camera position/vector? I have no idea how it might access these, or even if a VS _can_ pass values to the PS anyway?

Comment: Sure, VS get given face-normal and can access sight vector too (if you pass it to the VS). VS can pass values to the PS too. But this won't give you VFACE. At least not precisely because there are some corner cases where the two normals of a tri will be detected as front facing and the last one back facing (or two as back facing and one as front facing). This results in very unpleasant artefacts (I guess you are using VFACE for two side lighting purpose). This is due to attributes interpolation in the rasterizer. Only way to do it properly is to use two passes as I stated in my answer.

Comment: The _face_ normal is identical for every vertex of a triangle, I think you meant to say the VS can access _vertex_ normals, or _interpolated_ face normals? This is not for lighting, but your artifact point remains valid... however it might be worth a try.

Comment: Exactly, I mean VS can access vertex normals (the normal stored in the VB). Only PS can access interpolated normals or any other primitive interpolated attributes that the VS pass to the PS.